# Align jquery ui tool tipster icon with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a spot of trouble with aligning the tooltipster icon with a paragraph, here is my html code

```
<div class="tool-tipster" title="For example “8am to 5pm” or “Anytime”"></div>
<p class="information-section">Please tell us what hours you are available the following days.</p>
```

and here is my CSS so far

```
.form__primary.form__two-column .tooltipster-icon{
    float: right;
}
```

I basically want the tooltipster icon (?) to be next to "Please tell us what hours you are available the following days." here is an image to explain

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer

Basically I have told the paragraph and the div to both float left like so

HTML

```
<p class="information-section tooltipster-information-section">Please tell us what hours you are available the following days.</p>
<div class="tool-tipster" title="“IE: 2pm-5pm or All Day”"></div>
```

CSS

```
.form__primary.form__two-column .tooltipster-information-section {
    float: left;
}
.form__primary.form__two-column .tooltipster-icon{
    float: left;
}
```

Works in all browsers for me